# Options to get a higher email send limit

Tags: email

Realize there a lot of bulk email services, but what I'm trying to do doesn't feel like bulk email; though maybe I'm just thinking about it the wrong way. Case in point, I attempted to create an account on MailChimp and it wants a subscriber list.

I'm send one, and only one email per address; for example, replying to job postings on Craigslist. I'm not sending follow-up emails, and basically the first email I send is the last to an address unless I get a reply.

Sometimes the email I send is based on a template, other times they've asked for something, and I customize the email. I've automated creating resumes and sending emails in the past, but currently the fastest way just seems to manually do it; meaning I can't imagine sending more than 500 emails in a single day.

As far as I'm able to tell if Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, Lycos, AOL, etc. - do not offer the service of paying per email over the send limit, since I'd be willing to pay for the service and be done with this, as it's taking up a huge amount of time and overhead to deal with.

Currently, although I've seen sites giving higher numbers, most of the providers appear to limit emails sent to 20-40 a day; possible I'm doing something wrong, but if I am, I don't understand why these limits are not easy to see within an account, so I'm either able to stay within the limits, or see the service is not a good fit for my needs; currently I just get random error-messages, locked-out, etc.

(If needed, and the setup doesn't take more an a few hours, I'm more than willing to deal with configuring scripts, CSV files, templates, etc. on my computer - as long as they're well documented and the end result addresses the issue; meaning that if I have to send a one-off email, I just copy the template, make the changes, and point to the email. The system must also support attachments, since every email has at least one attachment; best solution would be if I'm able to load an attachment once to the system, then alias it in the local script.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mail account your internet service provider provides. It is unlikely that you hit their limits, and even if that happens, you, as a paying customer, can easily negotiate a higher limit.

Comment: +1 @Hontvári József Levente: Agree, though as it turns out I used public wifi, so paying for ISP just to send email would likely be a bad deal. That said, in case this is of use to someone else with the same issue, here's a link to the [send limits of web email services and ISP](http://helpmanual.info/templates/System/details.asp?id=31606&fetch=26546) -- which based on my experience are much lower than what's listed on that site, but those numbers are the same as I've seen on other sites and it's possible I'm just doing something that sets of a "hidden" control.